# Create three level of directories

Tags: linux

I need to make three levels of folders each numbered 0-9 so that I can access `files/1/2/3/123456.jpg`

```
mkdir {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}/{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}/{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
```

doesn't work.

I don't have SSH access to this Linux web server, so how would I go about doing this in Windows?

Comment: If you don't have SSH access, what protocol are you using then?

Comment: ftp and svn. I'm trying to create the folders locally on my windows development box.

Comment: Could you please be a little clearer? Are you attempting to make the folders on a Windows or a Linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mkdir command above can be simulated with a .bat-file. It's been a while since I last had to write .bat-files and I don't have any windows machine to test it on, but something like this should work (may need tweaking):

```
for /L %%f in (0,1,9) do (
  md %%f
  cd %%f
  for /L %%g in (0,1,9) do (
    md %%g
    cd %%g
    for /L %%h in (0,1,9) do (
      md %%h
    )
    cd ..
  )
  cd ..
)
```

As suggested by grawity, it can also be written like this since "md" should work like "mkdir -p":

```
for /L %%f in (0,1,9) do (
  for /L %%g in (0,1,9) do (
    for /L %%h in (0,1,9) do (
      md %%f/%%g/%%h
    )
  )
)
```

Or you could start working on a linux box instead, where everything is so much easier. ;)

Comment: `md %%f/%%g/%%h`

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from your question if you can execute commands on the remote server; if you can, add the `-p` switch to `mkdir` command to make it work.

```
$ mkdir -p {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}/{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}/{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
```